# HTML5 Canvas ScreenToIso

Tags: html, canvas, isometric

I am try create Isometric in HTML5 Canvas, but don't know how to convert HTML5 Canvas Screen coordinates to Isometric coordinates.
My code now is:

```
    var mouseX = 0;
    var mouseY = 0;
    function mouseCheck(event) {
        mouseX = event.pageX;
        mouseY = event.pageY;
    }
```

And I get Canvas coordinates. But how to convert this coordinates to Isometric coordinates? If I am something like use 16x16 tiles.

Thanks for everyone reply for this question and sorry for my English language.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to translate standard coords to isometric - you should use such formulas (cos(30)  = 0.866 & sin(30) = 0.5 are factors to use 30 degrees isometric projection)

```
xi = (y + x) * 0.866;
yi = (y - x) * 0.5;
```

So, if you want to do back translate - we can find our formula:

```
y = yi + xi / (0.866 * 2);
x = y - 2 * yi;
```

E.G. We have coords `[3, 1]` and wants to find isometric coords, so it is ease:

```
xi = (1 + 3) * 0.866 = 3.464;
yi = (1 - 3) * 0.5   = -1;
```

So, view coords of this cell is [3.464, -1]

E.G User clicked at `[5.2, 1]`. It is ease to count new value:

```
y = 1 + 5.2 / 1.732 = 4;
x = 4 - 2 * 1 = 2;
```

So, the clicked sell is `[4, 2]`

Example via LibCanvas: http://libcanvas.github.com/games/isometric/